# Customer Community Plus Users can not access case sharing

Tags: community, case, sharing

We have a lot of Users in Communities with Customer Community Plus licenses. 
An error appears if the user want to have access to Case Sharing. With any other license (e.g. Customer Community Partner) there is no error message shown.

Does anyone have experience with this or can I just not use Case Sharing with the Customer Community Plus license?

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: We show our own exception, which is called: UP2GO_2T.Utils.Object_Exception: Wrong Object Name "CaseShare"

Comment: Did you ever reach a resolution on this? Was the code at fault your own code or were you catching a system exception and throwing a new one? Just trying to see if we can make this useful to others.